# How to return a subclass from __new__ parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class parent and two subclasses child1(parent) and child2(parent) sort of like the following near code.
(edited to more properly show that the parent class is doing something)

```
class parent(object):
  name = None

  def __init__(self,e):
    # process the common attributes
    name = e.attrib['name']

  def __new__(cls,e):
    if e.attrib['type'] == 'c1':
      return child1(e)
    elif e.attrib['type'] == 'c2':
      return child2(e)
    else:
      raise 

class child1(parent):
  extra1 = None
  def __init__(self,e):
    super(e)
    # set attributes from e that are specific to type c1

class child2(parent):
  extra2 = None
  def __init__(self,e):
    super(e)
    # set attributes from e that are specific to type c2
```

The goal is to be able to  get the "right" class based on the value of the parameter.  So if I can say `obj = parent(element)` and `obj` will be either `child1` or `child2` depending on what the value of `element.attrib['type']` is.

Comment: And what problem are you having?

Comment: What is `super(e)` supposed to do there? Did you want `super(child1, self).__init__(e)`, or something different? (And if you _did_ want that… you'll need a `parent.__init__` that accepts that `e` argument…)

Comment: Yes, there should have been a `parent.__init__` to accept the e argument.

Comment: @kindall: element is from an xml document.  One option would be to have a dictionary of classes and then reference into the dictionary to create the "correct" class based on an attribute from the element.  I was hoping that I could hide that decision making in the parent class.

Comment: Why cannot you just use a function instead of messing with the parent class?

Comment: Your bare `raise` and your bare `super(e)` aren't doing anything helpful.

Comment: @ctjctj2: OK, but again, even with that `parent.__init__(self, e)`, you need to write the `super` call properly; `super(e)` is going to raise a `TypeError`, and it's not even clear what it's _supposed_ to mean…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that inside `parent.__new__`, you're calling `child1(e)`, while calls `child1.__new__`, which finds the implementation in `parent.__new__` and calls it with the same `e`, which calls `child1(e)`, which… so you get infinite recursion.

There are better ways to design this, but if you just want to fix your design, there are three options:

---

If you define `__new__` in all of your subclasses, it won't fall through the `parent.__new__`. You can do this in a single step by interposing an `intermediate` class between `parent` and `childN`, so you only need `intermediate.__new__`. Or use a mixin that they all inherit, or …

---

Get rid of the inheritance. Is there really any reason `child1` is-a `parent` here?

You seem to be looking for what in Smalltalk/ObjC terms is called a "class cluster", and you don't need the "visible face" of the cluster to be the base class in Python any more than you do in those languages.

For example:

```
class base(object):
    pass

class parent(base):
    def __new__(cls, e):
        # same as before

class child1(base):
    # etc.
```

In Python, you can even make `parent` an ABC, and `register` each `childN` with it so you can use `isinstance` and friends with it.

---

Finally, you can just catch the recursion by only handling `__new__` on `parent`, not its subclasses:

```
def __new__(cls, e):
    if cls is not parent:
        return super(parent, cls).__new__(cls)
```

Comment: in this __init__  of child1  gets called twice...am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

This is a lot easier if you don't have `parent` be a class at all, but just a normal function.

Using the base class is a pattern from languages where that's the only real way to do this. It's not necessary or helpful in Python.